# Getting the post_id in wp_ajax function

Tags: posts, functions, ajax

I wrote a custom AJAX function in which I have assigned a post type to be a child of another post type. In one function I am looping through those child posts, and I want to update the database to reflect the post_parent(the post which the child posts belong to).

Problem is, I cannot grab that post's ID from anywhere to update the db. Any suggestions?

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: 'new_item_save',
        item_order: $('#img-sortable').sortable('toArray').toString()

    }
});
```

And here is the PHP callback:

```
function save_new_img_order( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pid = $post->ID;

    $order   = explode( ',', $_POST[ 'item_order' ] );
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $order as $item_id ) {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'menu_order'  => $counter,
                                            'post_parent' => $pid,
        ), array( 'ID' => $item_id ) );
        $counter ++;
    }
    die( 1 );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_new_item_save', 'save_new_img_order' );
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [tag:wp-localize-script] to see how to properly pass data from PHP to javascript.

Answer (score 22):

Its an old question however would like to answer for other people

Within ajax function hooked to wp_ajax do this.

```
$url     = wp_get_referer();
$post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

Comment: It's more performant to just pass the ID from JavaScript, using `url_to_postid` requires querying the database.

Comment: That's right, but if you want to do it only server side, like in my case where I have to validate the post id.

Comment: very nice answer ! about performence... maybe it's less performant, but it is definitly more secure.

Comment: The referer can be spoofed. Not in a browser, but yes in scripting languages. A `nonce` should be used combined with a `current_user_can` check after which either this answer or TheDeadMedic's answer would be equally secure. And for public ajax endpoints, `is_post_publicly_viewable` should be used.

Comment: This is one of the best answers. You saved a lot of my time man!!!

Answer (score 2):

The ajax hook won't pass back a `$post` object to your callback - how on earth would it know to do so!

You need to send the data yourself:

```
data:{
    action: 'new_item_save',
    post_id: POST_ID_EITHER_PARSED_FROM_DOM_OR_PHP_ECHOED,
    item_order: $('#img-sortable').sortable('toArray').toString()
}
```

...and then grab it from `$_POST` in your handler:

```
function save_new_img_order() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    ...
}
```