# How to modify a global variable in a function and use it on another function?

Tags: php, variables, globals

Final state: As Nathan Johnson stated, I change my plug in to a class, still can't use post id in increment_like function...

```
<?php .... //irrelevant parts skipped
class wpse_263293 {
    protected $ID;

    //* Add actions on init
    public function init() {
    add_action( 'the_post', [ $this, 'createLikeButton' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', [ $this, 'footer' ] );
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',[ $this ,'button_js']);
    add_action('wp_ajax_increment_like', [$this,'increment_like']);
    add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_increment_like',[$this,'increment_like']);
}

public function footer() {
//* Print the ID property in the footer
echo $this->ID; //This one works
}
public function createLikeButton( $post ) {

  $this->ID = $post->ID;
  $myId=$post->ID;
  echo "<button onclick=\"likeButton()\" p style=\"font-size:10px\" id=\"likeButton\">LIKE</button>";
}
public function button_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'likeButton', plugins_url( '/like.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('likeButton', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_localize_script('likeButton', 'new_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

public function increment_like() {

    echo $this->ID."test"; //I only see test
    /* irrelevant code*/

}

}
//* Initiate the class and hook into init
add_action( 'init', [ $wpse_263293 = new wpse_263293(), 'init' ] );
?>
```

Comment: It is null when you echo from the PHP function or null `when i sent it via JQuery to a JS function.`? I don't see where you're sending it to JS.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that part because it was irrelevant, in javascript I use an alert box to see what echo prints  , but the point is it's null in the PHP function.

Comment: why not use the global outside of a function and set $myId right after then jsut call $myId without redeclaring global again?  other than that add $post_object to your function

Comment: I tried all of the things you said.

Comment: Are you certain you are calling do_something after the_post action fires and not before?

Comment: @Milo I'm calling it when a button is clicked on the post page, so it should be after the the_post action, isn't it?

Comment: When do you pass the variable from php to JavaScript? How does your php function get called from your is code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do it is to **not** use global variables.

This is a simple class that uses 3 methods and 1 property to hook into `the_post` and echo the post ID in the footer.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE_263293 Example
 */

class wpse_263293 {
  protected $ID;

  //* Add actions on init
  public function init() {
    add_action( 'the_post', [ $this, 'the_post' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', [ $this, 'footer' ] );
  }
  public function the_post( $post ) {
    //* Only do this once
    remove_action( 'the_post', [ $this, 'the_post' ] );

    //* This is the property we're interested in
    $this->ID = $post->ID;
  }
  public function footer() {
    //* Print the ID property in the footer
    echo $this->ID;
  }
}
//* Initiate the class and hook into init
add_action( 'init', [ $wpse_263293 = new wpse_263293(), 'init' ] );
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I'm not sure about how to use a class for a plugin. In examples on the tutorials, they are all about functions.

Comment: You can literally copy and paste the above code into a file in your `wp-content/plugins` folder and it will work. Or include it as part of your existing plugin (without the plugin header).

Comment: WPSE stands for WordPress StackExchange and 263293 is the number of your question. Feel free to use whatever name for the class that you wish. It has to be unique though.

Comment: I put all of my hooks to init() and functions to this class, I can see the page id as well on the footer, but still when I pressed the button, and I printed the $this->ID on the alert box, it's 0.

Comment: Then the issue is passing the variable to your javascript. Please open a new question showing how you're trying to pass the variable from PHP to javascript. (Hint: it should use wp_localize_script)

Comment: I edited my question to final situation... I am sure that javascript has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `wp_ajax_*` fires before `the_post`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's because  wp_ajax_* fires before the_post. 
I found the solution on the second answer of that question:
[Getting the post_id in wp_ajax function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59611/getting-the-post-id-in-wp-ajax-function)

```
 $url     = wp_get_referer();
 $post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```